# Read-only, encrypted flash drive

Tags: encryption, usb-flash-drive, read-only

Is there any hardware or software way to make a flash drive encrypted and read-only? I want to give this flash drive to someone, have them be able to open and read files, but not able to copy the file off of the flash drive or edit the files in any way.  I can't do anything about screenshots but I want to make sure that I can put this flash drive into the hands of the enemy and when they give it back, it will be exactly the way I gave it to them.

Is there anyone out there with experience using hardware encryption solutions like IronKey? Can they do something like this?

Comment: If they can open and read them, they can copy them.

Answer (score 1):

The CD is an example of a read only device. It will prevent changes being made to it, but copying is still unrestricted.

But what you describe is impossible. You want to give away digital information, but restrict how that information is used and limit it being transferred.  The big media has been trying to do exactly that for decades (using DRM), and failed  miserably.  In essence because it is impossible.

Encryption will not help you either, since you need to decrypt the information in order for it being useful (*open and read*).